# How to unpack an integer bit-pattern into a tf.Tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a biggish dataset stored relatively efficiently on disk, with one-hot vectors packed into the bits of a bunch of ints. The data format is fixed-width, so I can read it in fine with `tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset`, and with `tf.decode_raw()` and  `tf.bitwise.*` I have converted by input data into a pile of 64-bit integers representing the input vectors. But I am stumped at expanding the integer bit patterns into a tensor.

Concretely (using bytes instead of longs for the sake of brevity), let's say I get the value `0xba` (`0b10111010`). In that case I want to expand this to the vector `(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)`. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def bits_to_one_hot(bits, depth, dtype=None):
    bits = tf.convert_to_tensor(bits)
    masks = tf.bitwise.left_shift(tf.ones([], dtype=bits.dtype),
                                  tf.range(depth, dtype=bits.dtype))
    masked = tf.bitwise.bitwise_and(tf.expand_dims(bits, -1), masks)
    dtype = dtype or bits.dtype
    return tf.cast(tf.not_equal(masked, 0), dtype)

data = [0b10111010, 0b00101101]
depth = 8
input_bits = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None])
one_hot = bits_to_one_hot(input_bits, depth)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(one_hot, feed_dict={input_bits: data}))
```

Output:

```
[[0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0]]
```